# FCM onNewToken when is called and network access is granted? background and doze mode app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem when token expires and user does not open the app for a long time

I don't know how can I solve this problem! App notification works for 4 or 5 days, when token expires notifications stop!

This happens when user does not open the app for a long time, so onNewToken is called when app is in background or in doze mode? Maybe token expires on google server but onNewToken is not called because app is in background or in doze mode?

```
@Override
public void onNewToken(String token) {

    sendRegistrationToServer(this, token, 0);
    super.onNewToken(token);
}
```

In onNewToken I call sendRegistrationToServer which send token to my remote server and store it, this happens on first access when app is installed (so I'm sure it works) but no when "token changes"... 
I cannot everytime call a user to say: please open the app so notifications start again for 4/5 days ..

Someone has this problem? Could you help me to find a solution?

Comment: As far as i know, token doesn't expire like this, and best approach would be to store token in `sharedPref` like storages and send when user opens app i.e in login Api etc

Comment: I store new Token in the database (I deleted code when I past code), but my app need to receive notifications and I can't wait that user open app to send new token to my remote server!